# Как решить задачу о выравнивании земли?

Tags: алгоритм

Имеется следующая картинка. В каждом узле сетки дано некое значение(высота). В реальном мире это поверхность Земли c ямами и холмами(горками), и задача заключается в том что ее надо выровнять. Выровнять значит где-то засыпать ямы, а где то сровнять горы. Ни каких построек и водоемов нет. Земля с возвышенностей перераспределяется в ямы. Критерий оптимальности: как можно меньше земли пересыпать, ограничения: все можно ровнять и крайние точки тоже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть на входе у меня будет некий массив со значениями в узлах, например такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]